# A word to describe a person who dismantles electronic products

Tags: word-request

There are some Youtubers and Vloggers who make videos to show how they dismantle and/or modify electronic products like mobile phones, and maybe other kinds of stuff. Is there a word in English to describe such a person? Thanks.

Comment: Do they take the phones apart to show how they work, to repair them, to modify them, or to destroy them?

Comment: @alphabet Yes. I wonder if there is a more specific word to describe these people.

Comment: I'm asking which kind of people you are trying to describe.

Comment: @alphabet I thought "they" referred to the same group of persons no matter what they do after taking the phones apart, excluding those who destroy. Do they have different names if they do different things? Would you please teach me all the possible names?

Comment: Yes, they are hackers. Because you are not supposed to modify mobile phones unless they are simply repairing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms used to describe the kind of video tutorials you are referring to which demonstrate how an item is disassembled, either to carry out a specific repair or just to show how it is taken apart for the purpose of any repair, are '*teardown*' or '*disassembly*' videos.

I don't believe there's a specific word to describe the *person* who makes such videos. Chances are they don't just disassemble and reassemble things purposelessly. By trade, they may be an *electronics technician* or an *engineer*. If they are not qualified to be called that then they may just be an electronics *hobbyist* or *enthusiast*.

Answer (score 1):

Appending ***-er*** to *[**noun**]* is a "productive suffix" in English. It can be used to create a new noun meaning *person associated with [noun] in some way*. As per this [*Youtub**er...***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGxaqAxSR-M)

> *what kind of **teardowner** would I be if I didn't take it apart first? Enjoy!*

So just copy him. *In context*, I'm sure you'll be understood, just as I'm sure you understood my use of ***Youtuber***.